# mysql search query returns the same record x times

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT *, DATE(file_created) as created, s.disk_id, s.url, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE cmt_type=1 AND file_id=cmt_id) as comments FROM (files, servers s)
 WHERE usr_id=1 AND (file_name LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%') OR file_descr LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%')) 
ORDER BY file_created DESC
```

When I run this query I get 40 records back if there is atleast one record matching the query and all the 40 results will be the same record with the same ID!

I cant see any obvious problems with the query so not sure what is causing this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query, formatted so it is better understood:

```
SELECT *, DATE(file_created) as created, s.disk_id, s.url, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE cmt_type=1 AND file_id=cmt_id) as comments
FROM files, servers s
WHERE usr_id = 1 AND
      (file_name LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%') OR file_descr LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%')) 
ORDER BY file_created DESC
```

You have no `join` condition between `files` and `server`.  No surprise that you ware getting duplicates.  The comma in the `from` clause means `cross join` or "create a cartesian product".  Simply do not use commas in the `from` clause.  A simple rule that will save future frustration.

So, if the `file` has a server id, then you might want:

```
SELECT *, DATE(file_created) as created, s.disk_id, s.url, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE cmt_type=1 AND file_id=cmt_id) as comments
FROM files JOIN
     servers s
     ON files.serverid = s.serverid
WHERE usr_id = 1 AND
      (file_name LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%') OR file_descr LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%')) 
ORDER BY file_created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are joining two tables (`files` and `servers`) but I can't see anything to restrict the servers, so it's going to repeat each matching line of `files` with each matching line of `servers` (all of them, I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I think,


First, you should add joining criteria for tables like `files.server_id = servers.id` at the where statement.


Second, you should change `file_id=cmt_id` statement to `comments.file_id = file_id` for correct counts.

```
SELECT *, DATE(file_created) as created, s.disk_id, s.url, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments WHERE cmt_type=1 AND Comments.file_id = files.file_id) as comments
FROM (files, servers s)
WHERE files.file_server_id = s.server_id AND usr_id=1 AND (file_name LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%') OR file_descr LIKE CONCAT('%','sample','%')) 
ORDER BY file_created DESC
```

I hope, it works.

Comment: Can you show the OP what the full query would look like?

Comment: can you send me column names of files and servers ?